# Ffmpeg converting to HLS - video extremely low quality

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, transcoding, mpeg2-ts

I'm building a streaming webapp that uses FFMPEG. The client sends webcam video using FFMPEG (converting the webm stream into mpeg-ts in the process) over RTMP, and the media server receives the mpeg-ts stream, transcodes it into HLS with multiple quality levels for ABR (using a master playlist).

So far, I've got all of this working, except that my transcoding command creates HLS segments that are extremely low quality; the video is very pixellated, and the best quality level (1080p) just looks like 240p scaled up to 1080p. In order to test my FFMPEG command I remuxed a sample high quality 1080p movie into mpeg-ts (I checked the quality, it looks the same as the original), and I'm using this command to transcode this movie into HLS for the test :

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -filter_complex_threads 4 -vsync 1 -i output.ts -filter_complex 
"[v:0]split=5[s0][s1][s2][s3][s4]; 
[s0]scale=w=1920:h=1080:flags=lanczos,yadif[v0];
[s1]scale=w=1280:h=720:flags=lanczos,yadif[v1];
[s2]scale=w=854:h=480:flags=lanczos,yadif[v2];
[s3]scale=w=480:h=360:flags=lanczos,yadif[v3];
[s4]scale=w=426:h=240:flags=lanczos,yadif[v4]" 
-map "[v0]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 3400k -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v1]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1725k -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v2]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 960k -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v3]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 510k -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1  
-map "[v4]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 320k -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -af “aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0” 
-f hls -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1, v:2,a:2, v:3,a:3, v:4,a:4" 
-hls_wrap 24 -hls_time 10 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 "C:/Users/John/Desktop/ffmpeg-20181218-978c935-win64-static/bin/vs%v/manifest.m3u8"
```

I'm very new to FFMPEG, I referred to [this](https://videoblerg.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/how-to-create-abr-content-with-ffmpeg-in-one-pass/) article for the video options, and modified it to create HLS instead of mp4. Needless to say I botched this up pretty bad, although the command itself works and does what I need it to (other than the crappy quality). Could anyone help me optimize this command to make it transcode much less lossy video?

Comment: FWIW, this is a process we're trying to solve for at Mux, if you'd be interested in chatting about what you're building.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. I had two issues : the bitrate for each output was too low, and the command itself was wrong in that I used -b:v [bitrate] for all outputs instead of specifying the stream for each bitrate like -b:v:0 [bitrate]. The correct working output command is this :

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -filter_complex_threads 4 -vsync 1 -i output.ts -filter_complex 
"[v:0]split=5[s0][s1][s2][s3][s4]; 
[s0]scale=w=1920:h=1080:flags=lanczos,yadif[v0];
[s1]scale=w=1280:h=720:flags=lanczos,yadif[v1];
[s2]scale=w=854:h=480:flags=lanczos,yadif[v2];
[s3]scale=w=480:h=360:flags=lanczos,yadif[v3];
[s4]scale=w=426:h=240:flags=lanczos,yadif[v4]" 
-map "[v0]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:0 12M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 1920:h=1080 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v1]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:1 7.5M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 1280:h=720 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v2]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:2 4M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 854:h=480 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map "[v3]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:3 1.5M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 480:h=360 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1  
-map "[v4]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264 -b:v:4 1M -preset medium -profile:v baseline -keyint_min 24 -level 3.0 -s 426:h=240 -g 48 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -map_metadata -1 
-map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -map a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -af “aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0” 
-f hls -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1, v:2,a:2, v:3,a:3, v:4,a:4" 
-hls_wrap 24 -hls_time 10 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 "C:/Users/John/Desktop/ffmpeg-20181218-978c935-win64-static/bin/vs%v/manifest.m3u8"
```